# Converting a line-separated file into a list

Tags: python

So I have a file that look something like this:

```
 Apples
 Red
 Round

 Banana
 Yellow
 Long
```

I want to create a list where each 'group' is in a separate list like this:
[[Apples, Red, Round], [Banana, Yellow, Long]

I am completely stumped on how I should proceed.

Comment: Your first task is to read the file into a variable, [here are some examples of how to do that](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Here is also a [good introduction on lists](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists).

Answer (score 2):

We'll split on `\n\n` (two newlines) to separate the groups, then use regular `str.split` to divide those into items

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    l = list(map(str.split, f.read().split('\n\n')))
```

You can see a similar example (without the file I/O) running at [this repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MeaslyReliableMetalmarkbutterfly)

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the content once by a double newline in order to get each group separately, and then split each group individually:

```
with f = open('file.txt'):
    content = f.read()
    result = [group.split() for group in content.split('\n\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Short code is great but what if you have to maintain it 2 years later? ;-)

So here's my more human readable version which works like the existing versions:

```
file = open('file.txt')
text = file.read() # read everything into a string
file.close()
groups = text.split("\n\n") # create the groups
result = [ group.split("\n") for group in groups ] # split each group again at \n
```

This is two lines longer but I prefer this way because I am able to read and understand that easier than the other versions. However it's your decision. I hope I could help you.